# Find max row and its value in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table

```
ID    Level    Value
 1     1        10
 1     2        20
 1     3        15
 1     4        18
 2     2        12
 2     1        20
 3     1        50
 3     2        80
```

I want find the max level for each id and the value of this max row, Result :

```
ID    Level    Value
 1     4        18
 2     2        12
 3     2        80
```

I don't want use nested 'Select' because my table is too big and nested select slow down my query
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join and a test for null.

```
SELECT T.*
FROM T
LEFT OUTER JOIN T AS T2
ON T2.ID = T.ID AND T2.[Level] > T.[Level]
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

Untested in SQL Server 2000 but assuming `Level` and `Value` are both positive integers something like the following should work without needing a nested `SELECT`.

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(Level) AS Level,
       Max(Level * Cast(10000000000 AS NUMERIC(38)) + Value) 
                                              % 10000000000 AS Value
FROM   T
GROUP  BY ID
```

Or a version that copes with negative values

```
SELECT ID,
       Max(Level) AS Level,
       Cast(Substring(Max(CASE
                            WHEN Level < 0 THEN 0x00
                            ELSE 0x01
                          END + Cast(Level AS BINARY(4)) + 
                                Cast(Value AS BINARY(4))), 6, 4) AS INT) AS Value
FROM   T
GROUP  BY ID
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting idea. Couldn't you just use `max(Level)` for the second column?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how this 'magic' works, the level column is magnified a great amount and added to the value column.  This drags the value along with the level when max is applied.  Then the magnified level value is removed leaving the value.

Comment: @user1115206: if that answer helps you solve your problem, please get in the habit of **accepting** that answer provided. It's the right and polite thing to do on StackOverflow and serves as an incentive for others to continue to help those looking for answers. [See the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternative:

```
select T.* from 
(select ID, MAX(Level) as M_Level from T group by ID) Q, T
where Q.ID = T.ID and Q.M_Level = T.Level
```

I know you do not want a nested select, but it may be handy in different situations. I tested it with SQL Profiler with a couple of millions of rows, the performance difference is tolerable.